# How do I insert an id from one table to another?

Tags: python, sql

The main problem I am having is inserting the correct word id from one table to another based on the word the user had to guess.

```
cursor.execute (f"SELECT word_ID FROM WORDS WHERE word = puzzle_to_solve (SELECT puzzle_to_solve FROM WORDS WHERE word = puzzle_to_solve)")
conn.commit()

player_ID = cursor.lastrowid
statistics = (player_ID, word_ID, score)
cursor.execute (f"INSERT INTO STATISTICS ('{player_ID}', '{word_ID}', {score}) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", statistics)
conn.commit()
```

I expect the output to insert the correct player id, word id and score into the table in my database. The player id and score part of the query does work.

The error I am receiving is mentioned below:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

This error is appearing in the select statement line of code.

Comment: add `puzzle_to_solve` in single quotes in your select  query as `cursor.execute (f"SELECT word_ID, player_ID FROM WORDS WHERE word = 'puzzle_to_solve' ")`

Comment: I added the single quotes my query being         cursor.execute (f"SELECT word_ID, player_ID FROM WORDS, PLAYERS WHERE 'puzzle_to_solve' = '{word}'")
        conn.commit()

Comment: I still received a error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "t": syntax error

Comment: in your `INSERT` query check whether you are passing string values in `single quotes` .what type `player_ID`, `word_ID`, `score`  columns in DB? what values are coming in `statistics `

Comment: Can you take profiler call for this query and check if you are using `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

update your query to this:

```
cursor.execute (f"SELECT word_ID, player_ID FROM WORDS WHERE word = puzzle_to_solve")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: I have inserted the suggestion from above and altered it due to some errors still occurring.

Comment: I changed my query to:         cursor.execute (f"SELECT word_ID, player_ID FROM WORDS, PLAYERS WHERE puzzle_to_solve = '{word}'")
        conn.commit()

Comment: I am receiving the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "t": syntax error